# How to set innodb_buffer_pool_size in mysql in google cloud sql?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I can not set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` from the `edit` in the https://console.cloud.google.com . It just do not have this parameter.

I also can not set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` with the sql:

```
mysql> SET GLOBAL innodb_buffer_pool_size=2147483648;
ERROR 1227 (42000): Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation
```

Comment: The `real` problem is my google cloud sql instance always restart when the memory usage is near the machine RAM, the data size of non-commit transactions is bigger then 200M and the qps of sql is about 3K/s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not currently possible - we always set `innodb_buffer_pool_size` to something like 75% of machine RAM.

In your case it seems you need more memory for some per-connection buffers and less in `innodb_buffer_pool_size`. We have ideas on how to automatically detect such conditions and reduce `innodb_buffer_pool_size` but nothing in practice yet.

The practical workaround for you right now is to increase instance size: with more memory you will have more slack for per-transaction buffers. The other probably less practical workaround is to decrease load on the database by either having less concurrent queries running (try using connection pool with limited number of connections) or by simplifying them (less JOINs, etc).

Comment: It may be great that I can change the percent of `innodb_buffer_pool_size` in the range of 10% to 75%. I had use a connection pool.It will auto restart with 10 max concurrent 
 threads limit.It do not restart with 5 max threads, but 5 max concurrent threads is not enough for my use case. The sql i use do not have join.Just replace into xxx (xxx,xxx),(xxx,xxx) and select xx,xx from xx where xx in (xx,xx).I think the data size of non-commit transactions is too much right now.

Comment: Is this still the actual state for Google Cloud MySQL?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Kubernetes to deploy the instance, set the parameter in the paas.config.yaml
customDatabaseFlags:

- name: "innodb_buffer_pool_size"
  value: "2147483648"