# Google cloud sql incorrect innodb_buffer_pool_size?

Tags: google-cloud-sql

I upgraded my Cloud SQL machine from a 'db-f1-micro' 0.6GB RAM machine to a 'db-n1-standard-1' 3.75GB RAM machine last week. Running:

```sql
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;
```

The output is:

```
1375731712
```

which I believe is 1.38GB. Here's the memory utilization for the primary and replica:

[image: mem usage]

This seems oddly low for this machine type but researching ([How to set innodb_buffer_pool_size in mysql in google cloud sql?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46399994/how-to-set-innodb-buffer-pool-size-in-mysql-in-google-cloud-sql)) it doesn't appear I can alter the innodb_buffer_pool_size. Is this somehow dynamically set and slowly increasing over time? Doesn't appear to be near the 75-80% range google appears to aim for on these.

Comment: How large is your dataset? One thing is that it might just not be entirely cached yet. As you say, memory usage it's increasing. You can try to check this resizing process with `mysql> SHOW STATUS WHERE Variable_name='InnoDB_buffer_pool_resize_status';`, as indicated in the [MySQL docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_buffer_pool_resize_status).

Comment: Running the above comes back with zero rows. The DB is composed of 25 or so tables. Most tables are < 20,000 rows but one of the larger tables has around 48 million rows. Few others with 10 million rows each.

Answer (score 0):

What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`?

`innodb_buffer_pool_size` must always be equal to or a multiple of the product of these two values, and will be automatically adjusted to be so. Chunk size can only be modified at startup, as explained in [the docs page for InnoDB Buffer Pool Size configuration](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-buffer-pool-resize.html).

For Google CloudSQL in particular, not only the absolute, but also the relative size of the `innodb_buffer_pool_size` depends on instance type. I work for GCP support, and after some research in our documentation, I can tell that pool size is automatically configured based on an internal formula, which is subject to change. Improvements are being made to make instances more resilient against OOMs, and the buffer pool size has an important role in this.

So, it is expected behaviour that with your new instance type, and possibly different `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`, you might get a quite changed memory usage. Currently, the user does not have control over the `innodb_buffer_pool_size`.

Comment: Hi @alextru, `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` comes back with: Unknown system variable 'innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size' while `innodb_buffer_pool_instances` returns 1

Comment: Do your instances use MySQL 5.6? I've seen that `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` doesn't appear in the Variable Reference table for that version, but it does in the 5.7 one. So you need to upgrade your MySQL version to check that value. You can also try to increase the number of buffer pool instances to 2, to reduce contention. The pool size might readjust after that. See [this page](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-multiple-buffer-pools.html).

Comment: Upgrading to 5.7 isn't a realistic option right now for us. This is a live PROD instance and the regression testing needed to validate bumping to 5.7 didn't break anything isn't worth the effort to possibly get access to the `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` variable.

Comment: I understand. Well, in any case, if you want to change `innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size` and `innodb_buffer_pool_instances`, you have to restart the instance specifying the new values.